# Trying to pass a char[] to another in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, char

Ok, I have no idea what to do here:

```
struct
{
       char nombre[30];
       int codigo;     
 }productos[10];

int z = 0;
char tempchar[30]; 

for (z=0; z<9; z++)  {
           if (productos[z].codigo>productos[z+1].codigo) {           
              tempchar = productos[z].nombre;
              productos[z].nombre = productos[z+1].nombre;                  
              productos[z+1].nombre = tempchar;
           }
     }
```

I get the following error message: 
ISO C++ forbids assignment of arrays

There's obviously more code but I just included what it has to do with the error. 
I just want to sort the names of the product by code. So, what can I do here?

Comment: You can't assign arrays in C. If you're trying to copy the array, use `memcpy()`. If you want a variable to refer to the same array, use a pointer.

Comment: Don't use non-English identifiers on Stack Overflow please! And indent your code correctly!!!

Comment: I edited your question to remove blank lines. Please accept an answer if it fits.

Answer (score 4):

Is it in C or in C++?

In C you should use [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) to compare strings and [strcpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to copy them. Be very careful of [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (perhaps use `strncmp` and `strncpy` etc...). Ensure that all your strings are null-terminated. Use [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) for sorting.

In C++, you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) which knows about `<`; you can then use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort them. And if you use ordered containers like [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) they will be ordered by construction.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to assign `char` arrays

```
strcpy(tempchar, productos[z].nombre);
strcpy(productos[z].nombre, productos[z+1].nombre);
strcpy(productos[z+1].nombre, tempchar);
```

Answer (score 0):

When sorting an array of structs, you typically want to swap the whole struct, not just a single member. Luckily for you, the assignement operator works on structs, even if they contain arrays. So your sort algorithmus will be less buggy if you do this:

```
temp = productos[z]; 
productos[z] = productos[z+1];
productos[z+1] = temp;
```

(how to declare `temp` is left as exercise for the reader)

Alternatively, if you are allowed to use c++, you can do

```
std::swap(productos[z],productos[z+1]);
```

Just remember, your sort algorithmus is still buggy. You should lookup "bubblesort" for a dead easy sort algorithmus you can implement. Or even better, if this is not an exercise, use an existing implementation like `qsort` or `std::sort`

Answer (score 0):

there is another way

```
struct
{
  char *nombre = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
  int codigo;     
}productos[10];
int z = 0;
char *tempchar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);

for (z=0; z<9; z++)  {
  if (productos[z].codigo>productos[z+1].codigo) {           
          tempchar = productos[z].nombre;
          productos[z].nombre = productos[z+1].nombre;                  
          productos[z+1].nombre = tempchar;
       }
 }
```

Comment: You're leaking memory. `char *tempchar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);` and then `tempchar = productos[z].nombre;`